# What is the rationale of configuration files of neovim?

Tags: neovim

I switched to neovim some time ago, so I still have files from Vim.
I mean, `~/.config/nvim` and `~/.vim` coexist.
However I don't understand, for example:

- If I install  a plugin with vim-plug it goes to `~/.vim/plugged`
- If I add a word with spell checker it goes to `~/.config/nvim/spell/es.utf-8.add`

So, I wonder what is the rationale behind configuration files?

Comment: when you install a plugin using vim-plug do you not do `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')`, i.e., explicitly tell where to install to?

Comment: Yup, your comment it useful as an answer for question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### History of editor config file locations

vim and neovim are conceptually evolutions of much earlier editors *ed*, the standard editor, *ex*, ed extended, and *vi* the "visual" editor.  Since ex added a number of options which are configurable by the user, it uses a configuration file called `~/.exrc`.  This file consists of ex commands (`set`, `map`, etc) which are executed at startup of the program.  vi, initially being a visual mode for ex also uses `~/.exrc` with the same syntax.

Naturally, vim chose the logical next step, `~/.vimrc`.  Initially this also allowed a sequence of ex commands for setting simple options like `set autoindent`, but over time, this grew into a whole scripting langauge.  To allow for better organization of complex `vimrc`s, vim allowed the use of a directory `~/.vim/` (the user's runtime path) which can contain custom plugins and scripts.  Additionally, `~/.vim/vimrc` is allowed as an alternative to `~/.vimrc`.

In the 1976 unix environment where ex was developed (and even up to today) it was very common for a utility to store its configuration in a "dot-file" in the user's home directory (e.g., `~/.cshrc`, `~/.profile`).  When there were only a few programs which were configurable, this was not a problem.  However, when there are many complex programs, management of them all becomes difficult.

In the 2000s, the freedesktop.org project (originally the X Desktop Group, or XDG) developed a set of desktop standards, among these are the XDG user directories.  Under this scheme, applications should store their configuration files in (or in a subdirectory of) `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, which defaults to `~/.config/`.  This prevents applications from writing directly to the home directory.  One of the early modernization efforts which neovim took is to move its configuration location to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and user's runtime path to `~/.config/nvim/`.

#### The specific question

vim-plug allows you to choose whatever directory you want.  If you use `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')`, the files will be installed there.  If you want them in `~/.config/nvim/plugged` along with other neovim config files, you can just change the path.

Comment: If you call `plug#begin()` with no arguments, it will decide on the appropriate path depending on whether you're running Vim vs. NeoVim: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/a9bf5bd72212ff7cf9e9e863c365a3464faa2426/plug.vim#L158 . I believe it's `~/.local/share/nvim/plugged` for NeoVim. That is, of course, if you'd like to keep it separate for Vim vs. NeoVim, if you actually want to share the plug-in directory, then by all means pass a path to the call!